# Overriding generic return type from interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, overriding

I have several interfaces:

```
public interface Endpoint<T extends Fetchable> {    
    public Class<T> getFetchableType();
}

public interface Fetchable {
    ... fetched data fields
}

public interface Fetcher {
    public <T extends Fetchable> T fetch(Endpoint<T> endpoint);
}
```

For a class that implements `Fetcher`, why does the compiler work with this method declaration:

```
public FetchableImpl fetch(Endpoint endpoint) { return null;}
```

while these are both incorrect declarations:

```
public FetchableImpl fetch(EndpointImpl endpoint) { return null;}
--or--
public FetchableImpl fetch(Endpoint<FetchableImpl> endpoint) { return null;}
```

where `EndpointImpl implements Endpoint<FetchableImpl>`.

My intuition would be that the parameter would have something designating that it is an endpoint that deals with the specific type of Fetchable.  So why does the compiler require just a straight `Endpoint`, even when the interface method requires `Endpoint<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface method declaration requires a method that is able to deal with any type of `EndPoint`:

```
public <T extends Fetchable> T fetch(Endpoint<T> endpoint);
```

But in your method implementations you narrow it down to a more specific type of `EndPoint`.

```
public FetchableImpl fetch(EndpointImpl endpoint) { return null;}
public FetchableImpl fetch(Endpoint<FetchableImpl> endpoint) { return null;}
```

Hence, these are not valid implementations of the interface method. They don't cover all the cases that the interface requires.

You might want to declare a generic `Fetcher`, and then implement that:

```
public interface Fetcher<T extends Fetchable> {
    T fetch(Endpoint<T> endpoint);
}

public class FetcherImpl implements Fetcher<FetchableImpl> {
    public FetchableImpl fetch(Endpoint<FetchableImpl> endpoint) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want the `T` in `Endpoint<T>` to be the same as the `T` that is returned by the method, you can keep your interface method declaration as is, and use the same declaration in your implementing class:

```
public interface Fetcher {
    <T extends Fetchable> T fetch(Endpoint<T> endpoint);
}

public class FetcherImpl implements Fetcher {
    public <T extends Fetchable> T fetch(Endpoint<T> endpoint) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted the `T` in `Endpoint<T>` to be the same as the `T` that is returned by the method, how would I declare that in the interface?

Comment: The same as you have. And use the same declaration in your implementing class as well, including the type parameters.

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain why the first method is allowed? When the interface expects to return anything which extends Fetchable, the class is actually returning a specific class.

Comment: @CodeBender You're allowed to narrow down return types, but not parameter types. The interface says it expects a `<T extends Fetchable>` to be returned. A `FetchableImpl` extends `Fetchable`, so it's a valid return type.

Comment: @ Robby Cornelissen: Is it all about preserving the method signature while overriding?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the first works because of raw types, whereas the next two fail because of conflicts in the method signature after erasure.

For the longer explanation, remember that your `Fetcher::fetch` method is `<T extends Fetchable> T fetch(Endpoint<T>)`, and so implementers of `Fetcher` must implement that method. A good way of thinking of this is the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which basically says "if your static type is of SuperClass, then it shouldn't matter which SubClass you have, they should all just work as SuperClass says they do."

Let's see how your second two declarations do with that by imagining that someone has a `Fetcher` and invokes it as such:

```
Endpoint<IntFetchable> intEndpoint = whatever();
IntFetchable i = fetcher.fetch(intEndpoint); // T is inferred to be IntFetchable
```

As you can see, for that to work, the `fetch` method can't take `EndpointImpl` or `Endpoint<FetchableImpl>` -- it really needs to take an `Endpoint<T>`.

You could also disregard the generic altogether in your method signature, and have the override be of the raw type (that is, of the type-erased type). That's what you did with the first of your overrides (`FetchableImpl fetch(Endpoint)`), but raw types lose type safety and have a few other gotchas around them, so I wouldn't recommend it.

If you want fetchers to be specialized for each kind of endpoint, you should take the generic declaration and put it on the `Fetcher` interface:

```
public interface Fetcher<T> {
    T fetch(Endpoint<T> endpoint);
}
```

Now you can have a `FetcherImpl implements Fetcher<EndpointImpl>`.